# Post form data to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to submit the table row values of the rows that are checked to my controller.  My controller is always receiving a parameter of value null.

```
    @model IEnumerable<GoogleMapsAPIWeb.Models.Schedule>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Route", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <table id="schedulerTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col" >View</th>
                    <th scope="col">Site Id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var row in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(c=>row.isSelected)</td>
                                        <td class="smallerDataField">
                                            <a>View</a>@*TODO add code to view*@
                                        </td>
                                        <td><div class="smallerDataField">@row.SiteId</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input id="btnFindRoute" type="submit" value="Plan Route" />
    </div>
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Route(IEnumerable<Schedule> Schedules)
{
```

Comment: Does it return null if you check the box and then submit?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet of the HTML that is generated by `<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(c=>row.isSelected)</td>`?

Comment: <td><input id="row_isSelected" name="row.isSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="row.isSelected" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>

Comment: Have you tried @awesome's solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for` loop for this purpose. More [info](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection/)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
<tr>
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(c=> Model[i].isSelected)</td>
</tr>
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. That's nice to know! Haven't had to do this in MVC yet. I didn't realize the compiler generated different HTML for the names.